# RegEx for XSDDateTime

Tags: regex, date

I'm currently trying to build a Regex that matches/validates a XSDDateTime String. I found several on the web, but none of them makes a decent check for a February 31st and so on- and I'd like it to check for leap years as well.

What I got so far is

```
[1-9][0-9]{3}\-(0[1-9]|1[1-2])\-(0[1-9]|1[1-9]|2[])T(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(Z|\+|\-(0[1-9]|1[1-2]):(0[1-9]|1[1-2]))
```

but this won't throw an error for an 31st February...

Is there a proper RegEx for that I just didn't find yet? Because building one from scratch is really messy. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be regex? In what language are you doing this?

Comment: I'm doing it in PHP right now - but this should be rather language independent I guess

Comment: You shouldn't do it with regex, while, with some struggle, you can add february month specifications and what not, but you can't really deal with leap years, as regex and math don't go well together, not to mention you'd also have to include `year 2000` (which is not a leap year) and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datetime validation with regex is not safe. That is why almost every computing language has its own `DateTime` class and offers its parsing methods.

For PHP, you can extract valid-looking datetimes with [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/qG2rT5/2):

```
-?\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\.\d+)?(?:Z|\+\d{2}:\d{2}|\b)
```

and then use [`date_parse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php):

```
print_r(date_parse("2001-10-26T21:32:52"));
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/nkuYbs)

Comment: I know that the actual validation should be done in a "real" programming language. Just wanted something that checks most stuff in one command.

Comment: There are better ways to utilize regex than validating datetime values. There is one rule: if it  is easier and more maintainable to do without regex, do not use regex. It would be a long meaningless string difficult to adjust in case your datetime format changes.